# Nginx alternative listens

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, cluster

I have some Nginx servers which shares their configuration together because they are in a load balancer pool.

So I have a unique configuration for all servers and all servers are listening on *:80 and *:443 addresses.

But this is causing me some problems with the SSL certificates on clients which does not support SNI (like Windows XP).

To solve this I should specify a different IP address for each SSL website, but this is different from every server in the pool of course.

Do you have some advises?

Could I specify multiple IPs in the same server without causing an error in case Nginx cannot bind on one of them?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an instance where you might prefer to do centralized SSL termination.  Rather than have your `nginx` instances worry about SSL at all, just have them do http and centralize SSL termination on an `haproxy` box or redundant load balancers like A10 or Netscaler.  Your proxy/LB would then redirect the connection to the `nginx` boxes.  [This article](https://serversforhackers.com/using-ssl-certificates-with-haproxy) explains how to get SSL working on haproxy.

Comment: Don't know A10 and Netscaler, but `haproxy`, which I would totally recommend. +1 for this answer, as I fully agree.

Comment: Unless you've got buckets of cash the commercial load balancers can be safely ignored.  `haproxy` is just amazing in how many problems it solves.  :)

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm using the default load balancer of pfSense at the moment, so I should move to the haproxy package. I will check!

Comment: Hi Chicks, I'm thinking about your solution but..... I have a question: if I let the load balancer to handle the SSL certificates, they translate external HTTPS to internal HTTP, so I will have only one HTTP virtual host for each site. But... I want to redirect HTTP to HTTPS for some sites because I want to disable HTTP for them, so how I can avoid an infinite loop? Should I use two HTTP virtual hosts on different ports and use the secondary port for the HTTPS backend?

Comment: @Mat you should look at the [`X-Forwarded-Proto`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13111080/what-is-a-full-specification-of--http-header) header to see which protocol was requested.  If they requested http you can still redirect them to https.

Answer (score 2):

> Could I specify multiple IPs in the same server without causing an error in case Nginx cannot bind on one of them?

Not sure what OS you're running, because you didn't state this, but if it's some Linux flavor: Allow processes to bind / listen to / on "non-local" IPs.
To do so:

`echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_nonlocal_bind`

If you wan't to make this persistent, aka "across reboots", you have to put it "somewhere". For Debian based distributions, this would be for example `/etc/sysctl.conf`: Inside, put a line reading

```
net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind = 1
```

and execute `sysctl -p` or do a reboot.

Comment: Thank you gf! Yes I'm using Linux, good answer, let me try!

Comment: @Mat: Did this help?

Comment: Sorry for the delay.. The problem is that I'm in OpenVZ containers so I cannot set kernel parameters... I think the better way is to let the load balancer to manage the SSL certificates, but to do so I have to switch my actual load balancer (pfSense default load balancer) to haproxy.